# How to use variables in dbt macros

Tags: dbt

I am trying to use a variable passed in dbt run command in a macro. How can I use it

```
    {% set override_schema_name = vars('override_schema_name') %}


    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
    {%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}

        {{ default_schema }}

    {%- else -%}

        {{ default_schema }}_{{  override_schema_name| trim }}

    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}
```

In this example i am running dbt run --vars '{"override_schema_name":"someschema"}', but this is throwing error that variable is not defined.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things wrong in your code:

1. The macro name to access the value of a variable is `var`, not `vars`. So your first line should be `{% set override_schema_name = var('override_schema_name') %}`
2. You should declare any vars in your `project.yml` file before using them in a macro or elsewhere in your project:

```
name: my_dbt_project
version: 1.0.0

config-version: 2

# Define variables here
vars:
  override_schema_name: something
```

Alternatively, you can provide a default value to your `var` call in the macro:

```
{% set override_schema_name = var('override_schema_name', target.schema) %}
```

After making those changes, your `dbt run` command should work.

`var` docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/var
"Using Variables" guide: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-variables